# YII 2 : Adding new attribute inside option select2 kartik widget

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

i have script using yii 2 :

```
echo $form->field($model, 'data')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
     'data' => [array_merge(["" => ""], $data)],
     'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Select Data Name', 
            'multiple' => false,
     ],
]);
```

and the result in html :

```
<select id="storymapdata-data" class="form-control kv-hide input-md" name="Storymapdata[data]">
<optgroup label="0">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

and my question, 
how to add attribute 'data-type' inside option?, i want to like this :

```
<option value="1" data-type="wms">Option 1</option>
<option value="2" data-type="geojson">Option 2</option>
```

how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra attributes to the option tags through the options options (sounds funny...) configuration.

```
<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'data')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => [array_merge(["" => ""], $data)],
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select Data Name', 
        'multiple' => false,
        'options' => [
            '1' => ['data-type' => 'mws'],
            '2' => ['data-type' => 'geojson'],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

See the [Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList()-detail) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: that means i have to build all the options by specifying them, what if i have alot of phone numbers coming from the databases around 100 and i want to append a phone icon with all of them?